# Short hand for executing an algorithm in reverse

Tags: c#

Greetings stack overflow!

I have a method that executes when the checked state of a button is changed.
The method swaps out placeholder text within a rich text editor with pseudo data and vice versa. The user is able to drag the text from the data table onto the rich text editor.

`_dtFields` is a data table that contains the placeholder text and the corresponding pseudo data, my problem is this, on check state change, I loop through the entire data table to see if the rich text editor contains either placeholder text `bChecked = true` or if the editor contains pseudo data `bChecked = false` . Is there a more efficient way to swap out placeholder values with pseudo data other than what I have done here?

```
private void ViewMergedData(System.Boolean bChecked)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in _dtFields.Rows)
            {
                System.String sFieldName = "<<" + dr["fldFieldName"].ToString() + ">>";
                System.String sPsuedoData = dr["fldData"].ToString();

                //Check for fields on the document
                if (bChecked == true)
                {
                    //Replace with psuedo data
                    if (this.recEmailDesigner.Document.Text.Contains(sFieldName))
                    {
                        this.recEmailDesigner.Document.Text.Replace(sFieldName, sPsuedoData);
                    }
                }
                //Check for psuedo data on the document
                else if (this.recEmailDesigner.Document.Text.Contains(sPsuedoData))
                {
                    //replace with field name
                    this.recEmailDesigner.Document.Text.Replace(sPsuedoData, sFieldName);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replace your `sFieldName` and `sPseudoData` variables with a dynamic array of two strings, then select which is the "in" and "out" string using an index based on `bChecked`. Then you only need one 'instance' of your code that does the test and replacement:

```cs
    private void ViewMergedData(System.Boolean bChecked)
    {
        int index = bChecked ? 0 : 1;
        foreach (DataRow dr in _dtFields.Rows)
        {
            System.String[] sInOut =
            {
                "<<" + dr["fldFieldName"].ToString() + ">>", // [0] - was sFieldName
                dr["fldData"].ToString()                     // [1] - was sPseudoData
            };
            // Check for field name OR pseudo data on the document
            if (this.recEmailDesigner.Document.Text.Contains(sInOut[index]))
            {
                // Replace with psuedo data OR field name
                this.recEmailDesigner.Document.Text.Replace(sInOut[index], sInOut[1 - index]);
            }
        }
    }
```

The use of this `i` and `1 - i` "switch-back" is a common paradigm in `C` and `C++` coding, but there *may* be a more conventional and/or efficient way to to something similar in `C#` (in which language I am far less experienced).

Comment: This was very helpful and taught me something new. Thank you.